# access function on controller from app_controller, Cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

In CakePhp 1.3:

orry if this question is stupid, but I really don't know why my code is not working, maybe someone can point me in the right direction. My problem/question is: how can I access a function in a controller from the app_controller?

I have an app/controllers/items_controller.php:

```
class ItemsController extends AppController {
       ...
        function holaItem(){
            $i = 1;
            return $j = 2;
        }
        ...
}
```

app_controller.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
     var $uses = array('Item');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $result2 = $this->Item->holaItem();
    }
}
```

Why "$this->Item->holaItem()" is not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->Item` reference the `Item` model. However, the `holaItem()` method exists in the `Item` controller.

Either move it to your `Item` model or move the `beforeFilter()` to your `Item` controller.

I'd encourage you to read and understand how [CakePHP does MVC](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/890/Understanding-Model-View-Controller).

Comment: in other words, there is no way I can call a function within a controller from the app_controller, am I wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is no way. But it's uncommon in CakePHP to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try to use another approach. you are attempting to MVC model.

You can use a component for logical functions. [creating components](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/996/Creating-Components)